# Migrate php application to Kubernetes - How to pull code in containers?

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, deployment, containers

I am learning how Kubernetes works, with the objective of migrating a "Virtual Machine" environment to a "Kubernetes Container" environment.
The final objective is to be able to absorb peak loads (auto scaling).

**Currently,** we have a PHP web application (Symfony) running on multiple Debian VMs, which we call "Workers".
Each VM is a "worker", it owns the PHP source code, NGINX and PHP-FPM.

*PHP sessions are not a problem because they are stored in a cluster-redis.

The databases is stored in a cloud-provider.

The file storage is also in cloud-provider, S3 protocol.*

**With this environment** when we push code in production, **we do a git pull via Ansible** on all the "workers", and it works fine, nice !

**So now with Kubernetes ;**
I am a little confused to transcribe this operations in Kubernetes, more particularly the "source code" part.
I have already done this;

- Create PHP-FPM / NGINX services
- Create the PHP-FPM / NGINX deployments, with the nginx vhost stored in a configmap.

All this is working fine, my PHP / NGINX environment is up and running fine.

Now my biggest problem, how do I get the source code to run in my pods?

I thought about using an init container, which would make a "git clone" of my code when starting the pods, in a /code volume.
However, once the pods are up and running, how can I git pull them, kill them and reinitialize? Poor solution ?

The other idea I have is to do a Kubernetes Jobs, which I run every time it is necessary to pull new code?

Can you advise me ?
**What is the best solution for "git pull" code in running containers?** As I did before with my VMs, via a git pull from Ansible on all VMs.

Comment: @ Dreamsanon did David Maze'z answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

You would not update the code in a container itself. Instead you would build a new image from the code every time you release (or let your CI pipeline do that, assuming you have one). Then in a second step, you would tell kubernetes to recreate the container with the new image you just built.

Answer (score 1):

Your images should be self-contained, and pushed to a registry.  In pure Docker land, you should be able to run them without mounting the source code into them (no `docker run -v` or Compose `volumes:` options).  This means you need to `COPY` the source code into the image in a Dockerfile.

When you build an image, it's also very good practice to give every build a unique tag.  The source control commit ID is a good choice; a date stamp will also be pretty unique and is easier for an operator to understand.

```sh
docker build -t my/application:20210403 .
# run this _without_ separately injecting the application code
docker run -d -p 1234:1234 my/application:20210403
docker push my/application:20210403
```

In your Kubernetes Deployment spec there will be a line that references the `image:`, like

```yaml
image: my/application:20210403
```

When you have a new build of your application, build and push it as above, and change the tag in the `image:`.  (There is an imperative `kubectl` command that can do it; tools like Helm can inject it based on deploy-time parameters; or you can edit the YAML file, commit it to source control, and `kubectl apply -f` it.)  When the `image:` changes (and it must actually be a different string from before) Kubernetes will launch new pods with the new images, and then tear down the old pods.

This approach has a couple of advantages over what you describe.  In a multi-node or cloud-hosted environment, you don't need to manually copy code into the cluster; the image pull will do it for you.  If you discover something has gone wrong in a build, it's very easy to set the `image:` back to yesterday's build and go back.  This also uses only standard Kubernetes features and can literally be half the YAML size of a configuration that tries to separately inject the source code.

Comment: Thanks for this constructive response.

Is it necessary that i package everything in one and the same image (Nginx, PHP, Redis, Source code) or do I have the option to split this into multiple pods?

For example : An nginx pod, a php pod, a Redis-cluster pod, and a pod for my "source_code"?

In a way, NGINX / PHP pods access the source code through the "source_code" pods ?

If in an NGINX/PHP pod, I can turn up volume that point to another pod ?
This solution work ?

Comment: Nginx, Redis, and your application should be three separate Deployments.  "Source code" in isolation isn't a thing you can run, and doesn't need to be copied or deployed to the cluster separately from the application image.  There are no volumes in this setup.

Comment: David, if i `COPY` my source code in my PHP container, PHP has access to source code, nice ! But how Nginx access to code ? Do I have to copy code also, but not ideal with Symfony cache .. ? Or same container for Nginx/PHP ?